# What information is needed for a wire transfer?

Tags: united-states, wire-transfer, europe

I am used to wiring funds through SEPA by using IBAN and BIC codes. I just learned that these can't be used to electronically transfer money from the US to the EU.

My bank provided me with 4 codes:

1. bank code (e.g. AAAAA1AAAA)
2. routing number (e.g. 123456789)
3. IBAN Code
4. BIC code

According to my bank this should be enough to successfully transfer money from the US to the EU.

Will providing these numbers be sufficient for the wire transfer?  Is there a common template that all wiring instructions follow?

Comment: Did you ask the banks what they need? I've wired money, with no idea what's needed each time. The bank forms will tell you exactly what to bring.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer My bank tells me that is sufficient. I need to provide wiring instructions on an invoice. I am curious if there is a standard in "wiring instructions".

Comment: If you're wiring money from the US to an EU bank, you're pretty much throwing money away with a wire transfer unless it is really time sensitive.  I would recommend using a service like XE or US Forex for the transfer instead.

Answer (score 1):

IBAN is enough within [SEPA](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/paym/retpaym/html/index.en.html) and it should be so for your bank as well. Tell them to join our decade, or change bank.

I received bank transfers from other continents to my SEPA account in the past and I don't remember ever needing to say more than my IBAN and BIC. Banks can ask all sorts of useless information, but if your bank doesn't have a standard (online) form for the operation then it probably means you're going to spend a lot.